# How Do I give the active menu items a different color - HTML5 CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to add a different color to my active menu items.

I have tried a few different ways but, there must be something I'm missing.

Here is my code:

```css
#menu ul {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #3d4449;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-family: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu ul a,
#menu ul span {
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.625em 0;
}
#menu ul a:hover,
#menu ul span:hover {
  color: #efa341;
}
#menu ul a.opener,
#menu ul span.opener {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul a.opener:before,
#menu ul span.opener:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}
#menu ul a.opener:before,
#menu ul span.opener:before {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -ms-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #9fa3a6;
  content: '\f078';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#menu ul a.opener:hover:before,
#menu ul span.opener:hover:before {
  color: #eda547;
}
#menu ul a.opener.active + ul,
#menu ul span.opener.active + ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul a.opener.active:before,
#menu ul span.opener.active:before {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
#menu > ul > li {
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
#menu > ul > li > ul {
  color: #9fa3a6;
  display: none;
  margin: 0.5em 0 1.5em 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
#menu > ul > li > ul a,
#menu > ul > li > ul span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#menu > ul > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0.125em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.125em 0 0 0;
}
#menu > ul > li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <header class="major">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="opener">Services</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="webdevelopment.html">Web Development</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="customisedsoftwaredevelopment.html">Customised Software Development</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ecommercesolutions.html">E-commerce Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="softwaremaintenance.html">Software Maintenace</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Products</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="ikat.html">Practice Management Application</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Itrack.html">Electronic Claims</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iportals.html">Electronic Invoicing</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="dalymorgan.html">Debt Recovery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ibridge.html">Automated account collection</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="lms.html">Learner Management System</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? You mean your styles aren't applied? Is the class "active" even set on the elements you're trying to add color to?

Comment: Yes but i would like the tab to return to its normal (un-styled) state when i go to a new page, and the next pages menu tab should then be styled.

Comment: How do you set the menu tab active/how does the class get applied to the tab? How does your page know if it's active?

Comment: You need **Javascript**. There are many questions on this - Try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027629/changing-css-for-link-of-current-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply class like "active" to respective menu and apply css to it

like

```
#menu ul > li.active > a{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a `class` to the `active` menu item.

For example:

```css
#menu ul > li.active > a{
  color: red;
  background:yellow;
}
```

Adding the css from above to your code gives you this result:

```css
#menu ul {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #3d4449;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-family: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu ul a,
#menu ul span {
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.625em 0;
}
#menu ul a:hover,
#menu ul span:hover {
  color: #efa341;
}
#menu ul a.opener,
#menu ul span.opener {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul > li.active > a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <header class="major">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="opener">Services</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="webdevelopment.html">Web Development</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="customisedsoftwaredevelopment.html">Customised Software Development</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ecommercesolutions.html">E-commerce Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="softwaremaintenance.html">Software Maintenace</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Products</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="ikat.html">Practice Management Application</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Itrack.html">Electronic Claims</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iportals.html">Electronic Invoicing</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="dalymorgan.html">Debt Recovery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ibridge.html">Automated account collection</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="lms.html">Learner Management System</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: the (home) tab stays red when I activate a new menu item. i would like the tabs to be styled when i am on that specific page, and the rest to return to normal.

Comment: You need to add the class to the correct menu item. I assume you are making a static website?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `link:active` in CSS like this:

```
menu ul a:active,
menu ul span:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

It will allow you to adjust whatever you need when the link is clicked and active.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

- You want to have active menu items to be styled differently
- To achieve this without using JavaScript you have to add a class like "active" (as mentioned above) to your list item tag
- You have to do that for each site with its active menu item

Also prefer to change style for list element (like Rahul's answer) rather than applying it to the `ul`class like you did in your css.

Answer (score 0):

#menu > li.active > a{ color: #f46e28; }
this will help you definitely.