# Using jQuery to highlight currently selected link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to underline the currently selected link in my navbar, the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/9bkh4w8s/1/ is working(you have to expand the output). The code below is not:

html (`href` values were set to '`#'` in jsfiddle, here they have actual values):

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">JobBoard</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated == False %}
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link right-link" href="% url 'index' %}">Job Search<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'employer_signup' %}">Post a Job<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
                {% endif %}
<!-- set of links to be displayed if user is logged in intentionally omitted-->
        </nav>
```

css (same as jsfiddle):

```
.active{
  position:relative;
}
.active:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:1px;
  background:#000;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  margin-top:.5rem;
}
```

jquery (same as jsfiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })

});
```

When I click the 'Post Job' link:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'employer_signup' %}">Post a Job<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

It takes me to right page but the 'Job Search' link remains underlined and not the 'Post Job' link. The only difference between this and the jsfiddle is that I am actually being brought to a new page. Does anyone know why this ceases to work when `href` has an actual value?

Comment: This has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863396/dynamically-change-css-of-link-based-on-current-page

Comment: Try adding `target="_blank"` to the anchor tags (`<a>`) where the **href** attributes are defined, so the page will open on new tab. I think the problem is your page is reloading to his initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Because the link is redirecting to a new page it refreshes the content to it's original setting. You can set your nav link active by using url.